# How to detect URL to different page (also in the same domain)

Tags: java, url, uri, jsoup

I have question about detect url in page. I'm founding the best way how it solve. For downloading page I use Jsoup.

```
URI uri = new URI("http://www.niocchi.com/");
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri.toString()).get();
Elements links = doc.select("a")
```

And this page get me some links. For example this:

```
http://www.niocchi.com/#Package organization
http://www.niocchi.com/#Architecture
http://www.linkedin.com/in/ivanprado
http://www.niocchi.com/examples/
```

I need get only different pages without references to paragraphs.
I would like to get from example this:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/in/ivanprado
http://www.niocchi.com/examples/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to select only these `<a>` with `href` attribute with value build from characters which are not `#`. In that case you can use

```
doc.select("a[href~=^[^#]+$]")
```

`attribute~=regex` is syntax used to check if part of value of `attribute` can be matched with regex.

- regex accepting one or more non `#` characters can look like this `[^#]+`
- regex accepting only entire string (not only its part) need to be surrounded with `^` and `$` [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) which represents

  - `^` - start of the string,
  - `$` end of the string.

Comment: Thanks. And I have still one question. This regex get me links to files for downloading. Me I need only web page. What is good way for this?

Comment: @basfot Stack Overflow doesn't work this way, it is not discussion forum but `specific question`/`specific answers` site. If you have different problem then create [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you will describe your new problem in more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert them to strings and then split them based on the # mark.

for example:

```
public void stringSplitter() {
        String result = null;
        // example
        String[] stringURL = {"http://www.niocchi.com/#Package organization", "http://www.niocchi.com/#Architecture", 
                "http://www.linkedin.com/in/ivanprado", "http://www.niocchi.com/examples/ "};

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < stringURL.length; i++) {
            String [] parts = stringURL[i].split("#");

            result = parts[0];
            System.out.println(result);
            }
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

The output is:

```
http://www.niocchi.com/
http://www.niocchi.com/
http://www.linkedin.com/in/ivanprado
http://www.niocchi.com/examples/
```

I would even think about setting a part of the method to return only unique URL's